# How to filter based on selection?

Tags: javascript

Please tell me how I can filter and leave only those cards in block 3 that will correspond to the choice in the first and second blocks. (the first and second blocks are independent of each other, the results in the third block depend on the choices in the first two)

The first items are selected by default. If there are more than 4 cards in the third block, then show the first 4, and hide the rest.

https://jsfiddle.net/42fh68w0/1/

```js
const step1_items = document.querySelector('.step-1').querySelectorAll('.item');
const step2_items = document.querySelector('.step-2').querySelectorAll('.item');
const stepCards = document.querySelector('.step-3').querySelectorAll('.card');

step1_items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    step1_items.forEach(function(item) {
      item.classList.remove('item_active');
    });
    this.classList.add('item_active');
  });
})

step2_items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    step2_items.forEach(function(item) {
      item.classList.remove('item_active');
    });
    this.classList.add('item_active');
  });
})

stepCards.forEach(function(item) {
  item.style.display = 'block'
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.step-1,
.step-2 {
  border: 1px solid #009ce1;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.sign {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #5b6d89;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  padding-left: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #008ed1;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

.item::before {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #008ed1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.item_active::before {
  background-color: #008ed1;
}

.item:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

.step-3 {
  border: 1px solid #009ce1;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #008ed1;
  border: 1px solid #008ed1;
}

.card__more {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ee8853;
  border: 1px solid #ee8853;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="step-1">
    <span class="sign">Streaming service</span>
    <li class="item item_active">Netflix</li>
    <li class="item">HBO Max</li>
    <li class="item">Hulu</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="step-2">
    <span class="sign">Movie genre</span>
    <li class="item item_active">Comedies</li>
    <li class="item">Actions</li>
    <li class="item">Horrors</li>
    <li class="item">Drama</li>
    <li class="item">Fantasy</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="step-3">
    <span class="sign">Choose</span>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix comedy 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix comedy 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix comedy 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix comedy 4
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      Netflix actions 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix actions 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix actions 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      Netflix horrors 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix horrors 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix horrors 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix horrors 4
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      Netflix drama 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix drama 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      Netflix fantasy 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix fantasy 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix fantasy 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix fantasy 4
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Netflix fantasy 5
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>


    <li class="card">
      HBO Max comedy 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max comedy 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max comedy 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      HBO Max actions 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max actions 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max actions 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max actions 4
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      HBO Max horrors 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max horrors 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max horrors 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max horrors 4
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      HBO Max drama 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max drama 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max drama 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max drama 4
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      HBO Max fantasy 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max fantasy 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max fantasy 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max fantasy 4
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      HBO Max fantasy 5
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>


    <li class="card">
      Hulu comedy 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu comedy 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      Hulu actions 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu actions 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu actions 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu actions 4
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu actions 5
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu actions 6
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      Hulu horrors 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu horrors 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu horrors 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      Hulu drama 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu drama 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu drama 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu drama 4
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu drama 6
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      Hulu fantasy 1
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu fantasy 2
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu fantasy 3
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu fantasy 4
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      Hulu fantasy 5
      <a href="#" class="card__more">more info</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this javascript code

```js
const step1_items = document.querySelector('.step-1').querySelectorAll('.item');
const step2_items = document.querySelector('.step-2').querySelectorAll('.item');
const stepCards = document.querySelector('.step-3').querySelectorAll('.card');

let service = "Netflix", movieGenre = "Comedies";


step1_items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    step1_items.forEach(function(item) {
      item.classList.remove('item_active');
    });
    this.classList.add('item_active');
    service = this.textContent
    showChosen(service,movieGenre);
  });
})

step2_items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    step2_items.forEach(function(item) {
      item.classList.remove('item_active');
    });
    this.classList.add('item_active');
    movieGenre = this.textContent
    showChosen(service,movieGenre);
  });
})

stepCards.forEach(function(item) {
  item.style.display = 'block'
});



function showChosen(service,genre){
  const allCards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
  console.log(service + genre)
  for(card of allCards){
     if(card.textContent.includes(service)&&card.textContent.includes(genre.toLowerCase())){
      card.style.display = "block"
    }else{
      card.style.display = "none"
    }
  }
}
```

it just iterates over the elements and hides inactive

by the way, don't use querySelector, use .getElementsByClassName/.getElementById because they are much faster

I tried to not touch your already written code as much as possible